# Can i pass a javascript object back to an atk4 page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jqplot, atk4

From an ATK4 page, i can call jqplot using a javascript helper file like this

on the page

```
   $chart = $p->add('jqplot', null, 'chart1');
   $chart->setSeries(array(10,20,15));
```

define a jqplot.php like this

```
class jqplot extends View {
  function render()
  {
    $plot=$this->js(true)->univ()->jqplot($this->series, $this->opts);
    parent::render();
    return $this;
  }
}
```

and in a js helper file, link the php call to the javascript

```
$.each({
 jqplot: function(series, opts){
   console.log('jqplot series',series);
   console.log('jqplot options',opts);
   $plot=$.jqplot(this.jquery.attr("id"), series, opts);
   return $plot;   
 }
```

}

If i have one chart on a page and reload it with an ajaxec call, it works fine but if i have several charts next to each other, only the first one is ok and the one next to it completely disappears if i call reload.

What i really want to do is call the jqplot replot function on the chart and pass it new data from the page but how can i do this ?  The $plot object in the jshelper holds a javascript object and i need this object to call replot on it.

I am thinking maybe i can store the object when first created in a javascript associative array and then when i call replot, lookup the id and if found, call replot on the object but not sure what this code looks like or whether i have the right approach so any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance for you assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably would be quite difficult to achieve this. First you need to properly handle destruction of jqPlot. You'll need a proper jQuery UI widget capable of restoring everything through a de-constructor. Then you might get it to work.

As far as Agile Toolkit is concern, it destroys the element containing your jqPlot using JavaScript, re-loads HTML and re-executes JavaScript.

Comment: But would it be possible in the .js helper to store as a session variable the javascript object. If i put it in an associative array with the key being the div id, then when replot is called, the js helper could retrieve the original object and modify it ? So not really getting it back to atk4, just storing the javascript object instead of using an ajaxec to reload.

Comment: are you looking to save the state of JavaScript widget in ATK4 session? I suppose you could do that. Why do you need to refresh page anyway? Perhaps instead of calling reload simply call the replot. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve in general?

Comment: At the moment i am reloading the element containing the chart but when there are two charts side by side, this causes one of them to completely disappear before being redrawn.  I really want to call replot but with jqplot, the replot function requires the javascript object used when the chart was first created conceptually something like  series=1,2,3;  chart=jqplot(divname, series, options);  newseries=4,5,6; chart.replot(newseries);.  Problem is i think i need to save chart somewhere when i create the chart and this is a client side object.